# Transform file full-content nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, stream, filesystems

I am building a website with NodeJS which asks for a data-file to be uploaded, then I have to check and (if needed) transform the content of this file.

The source file is a JSON or XML configuration file, I just need to ensure its content is well-formatted for the rest of the application.

I am wondering what would be the best way to check the global file's content.

I usually manipulate files with Streams, but I am not sure if it allows me to do what I want...

The source file has a similar format :

```
{
    "parameters": [{
        "name": "name",
        "settings": {
            "key": "value"
        }
    }],
    "data": [{
        "id": "1",
        "label": "label 1",
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "label": "label 2"
    }]
}
```

What I need to do is to parse the file's content, and check if the file-format is good ;
Otherwise transform the file to a well-formatted one :

```
// Read the file content

var parameters = [],
    data = [],
    p = parameters.length,
    d = data.length;

// Loop on the parameters, and check the format
while (p--) {
    var parameter = parameters[p];

    if (name in parameter && typeof parameter.name == "string") {
        // Add several rules

        parameters.push(parameter);
    }
}

// Do a similar control for "data".

// Then save the well-formatted parameters and data into a file
```

The thing is that the uploaded file might be very large...
Can I perform it with transform Streams ? Because I need to check the full-content of the file as a object !
How can I be sure a Stream transformer won't give a chunk with just a part of data, for instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first try something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

try {
    var inputFile = require('./config.json');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);  // Do proper error handling.
}

// Loop on the parameters, and check the format
if (!'parameters' in inputFile) {
    console.log("Got a problem here!");
}

var parameters = [];
var p = inputFile['parameters'].length;

while(p--) {
    var parameter = inputFile['parameters'][p];

    if ('name' in parameter && typeof parameter.name == 'string') {
        // Add several rules
        parameters.push(parameter);
    }
}

// Do a similar control for "data".
var data = inputFile['data'];
// More code needed here...

// Then save the well-formatted parameters and data into a file
fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', JSON.stringify({parameters: parameters, data: data}, null, 4) , 'utf-8');
```

If you are dealing with mammoth files that cannot fit into memory, you've got a HUGELY more difficult task ahead of you.  In general, you cannot guarantee that a partial read will give you enough of the JSON to parse anything out of (e.g. `{"data": ["<FOUR PETABYTE STRING>"]}`).

Comment: File Reading instead of streaming... I'm affraid this is a limit, but I will inform the users about it, I don't think anyone has a <FOUR PETABYTE STRING>. Otherwise I can't help him anyway :)

Comment: BTW, what is the interest of using "require" instead of NodeJS file system ?

Comment: `require` on a .json file combines the file-reading and JSON parsing into a single command.  Do keep in mind that it will cache the result, so a server restart is necessary when changing that file.

Comment: Didn't really think about it, thanks for your help !